# Does charging time of a series of resistance and capacitor depend on the applied voltage?

Tags: capacitance

Cause I found out that you can calculate the capacitance by t=rc (time constant equals resistance times capacitance). But where I got confused was the charging source. Intuitively I would think if you hooked higher voltage up to it, then you'd get faster charging, but then you'd get different rc, but r and c are supposed to be constants. Put another way hooking up a 1000 uF cap in series with a 100k ohm resistor, up to a 9V battery would give one charge time, and then if you put a couple more nine volt batteries in series that would give a shorter time, but you still have a 1000 uF cap in there... what the heck?

Comment: If you want an intuitive way to think about it, the higher voltage also means a higher final charge on the capacitor, so it's very much a situation where you're charging "twice as fast" but also charging "twice as much" and so the time to charge turns out to be the same. This argument is a little inexact because you never get 100% of the way there, but the reasoning still holds if you work it out in terms of differentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time constant of the circuit doesn't change.

Charging 1000 uF through 100 kohms, the time constant is 100 s.

This gives the time it will take for the capacitor voltage to reach 63% of its final value. However the final value will of course be 18 V when charging with an 18 V source, and 9 V when charging with a 9 V source.

This means that the charging current, and the rate of change of the capacitor voltage will both be higher when charging with the higher-voltage source.

Also, if you defined the "charging time" to be the time to reach some fixed intermediate voltage, rather than reaching the final equilibrium voltage, then it will be shorter when charging with the higher voltage source. For example, if you define the charging time to be the time it takes the capacitor voltage to reach 1 V, then it will take about 11.8 s when using a 9 V source or 5.7 s when using an 18 V source.